# Symbols in Mathematica (#, & etc)

Tags: programming, core-language

I am constantly finding a lot of examples of usage of symbols

```
#
&
```

etc in the code. But I could not find any information what they actually mean and how to use them properly. Maybe I am searching wrong and they are not called "symbols" (I also searched for "operators"). Where can I find information about them?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: Go to Help > Documentation Center and enter one. That should take you to either a reference page, or a set of links to reference pages, for appropriate `FullForm` names of these operators.